# Recursively highlight any PDF with duplicate filenames

Tags: linux, shell, rhel-7

I have a 6TB set of files that need old versions of the PDF highlighted with over 2 million assets. This would need to be recursive. I'd have to do this via the Linux command line.

A, typical structure is below.

> ```
> Folder
> ------ Abc_V1.pdf
> ------ Abc_V2.pdf
> ------ Abc_V3.pdf
> ------ 123_456_V5.pdf
> ------ 123_456_V6.pdf
> ------ 123_456_V7.pdf
> ------ QWERT_V1.pdf
> ```

Of the above, I'd want to highlight the ABC and 123_456 PDFs as they have more than one version in the same folder.

Anything with one version we can ignore. 70% of the folders on the system are estimated to have just one version. I'm not concerned with them.

Every PDF on the system ends with an underscore and version number. The version numbers can go up to 20.

Everything before the last underscore and version number is the exact same filename as the previous version.

So the find and compare would run on everything before the final underscore and if it found more than one it would highlight it. This would only be for PDFs.

I can run the command as root and the OS is RHEL7. It's an interesting one I've not had much luck with this far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first attempt. Let me know if I'm on the right track.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' |perl -pe 's|^\./||; s|_[vV][0-9]+\.[pP][dD][fF]$||;' |sort |uniq --repeated
```

Explanation:

- `find . -type f -iname '*.pdf'` - list all PDF files in the current directory and subdirectories
- `|perl -pe 's|^\./||;'` - remove `./` at the start of each line
- `|perl -pe 's|_[vV][0-9]+\.[pP][dD][fF]$||;'` - remove `_v9.pdf` at the end of each line
- `|sort` - self-explanitory (`find` doesn't sort, and `uniq` requires sorted input)
- `|uniq --repeated` - only show lines that repeat, 1 each

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much. I've up voted your answer but with less than 15 reputation it's not showing. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. You could mark it as the accepted answer.